# Object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr' trying to prependTo() html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using reg-ex(div.rc > .r > a) to get div's anchor from html. Using setAttribute method to set attributes of reg-ex matched elemets. When I am try to prepend value to anchor tag it is showing **Object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'attr'** . Can anyone tell me how to add html to anchor using prependTo() method.

```
var pattern = "div.rc > .r > a";
$(pattern, document).each(function() {
  g(this);
});

function g(f){
    console.log(f.getAttribute("href"));                     
    var header = "<h2>sdfds fdsj fjds jfd s</h2>";
    header.prependTo(f);
}
```

Thanks.

**Answer:**

```
$('<h2>sdfds fdsj fjds jfd s</h2>').prependTo(f);
```

Comment: You are probably using DOM object wrap it with $(yourObject) to call attr on it

Comment: I modified my question added code...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I got the answer. I updated my question with answer.